# Pass complete html page to method in ts file angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a group for one module example login. This group contains `module.ts`, `html`, `spec.ts` and `page.ts`.

I have to write one function in page.ts which will have parameter as a complete HTML page. So I have to write something like this.

```
func replacingHTMLPlaceHolde(<pass html page here>) <return same html page after replacing>:{}
```

How can I do this? I have to call this function from `ionViewDidEnter()` method.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here (interpolation may be)? There may be a better way to implement it in the angular way if you share a bit more details on the rest of your code

Comment: I have html page coming from the backend directly, which is having some placeholder name for the class. in my code I want to pass that html page to a method and check for that placeholder and if matches then replace that placeholder with a new one. I don't have control over html page coming from the server. so I want to render that page and update my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option I see you could go with is use the server-side html as a string, and use a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) to replace as you need.

So something along this example (of course, replace what's needed for your own use case):

**your-component.ts**

```js
export class YourComponent {
  public serverHtml: string =
    "<div><h2>Block 1</h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div><div><h2>Block 2</h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>";
}
```

**your-component.html**

```html
<div [innerHTML]="serverHtml | replacePlaceHolder"></div>
```

**replace-placeholder.pipe.ts**

```js
import { Pipe } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: "replacePlaceHolder" })
export class ReplacePlaceHolderPipe {
  transform(value: string): string {
    return value.replaceAll("ipsum", "ipsos");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did the same and it worked for me.